# File upload with Multer and Uppy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, uppy

I'm using Uppy as my drag and drop file upload, but as we all know that Uppy doesn't take care of actually uploading it to the server. Therefore, I am using Multer as my back-end for uploading files to my server. Though, I ran into a snag. When I upload the file, I have multer change the file name to the current date plus the extension. But when I console log it, it comes out "undefined".

functions.js

```
let path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');



let myUploadFunction = function _multerFunction(req, res, filePath){


    let newFileName;

    let storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, filePath);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            console.log("Storage Function " , file);
            callback(null, newFileName = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));

            getNewFileName(newFileName); // Trying to pass this function to the upload.js route but it comes back undefined.

        }
    });

    let upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any();

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file. "+ err);
        }
        console.log("New File Name " + newFileName); // This console log does print the new file name

    });

};

let getNewFileName = function getNewCreatedFileName(fileName){
   return fileName;
};

module.exports.myUploadFunction = myUploadFunction;
module.exports.getNewFileName = getNewFileName;
```

upload.js

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

let upload = require('../functions/functions');

//const mysql_connection = require('../db'); // Database connection file.

/* POST upload route. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  upload.myUploadFunction(req, res, 'public/images', 'File is upload successfully');

   console.log("From the upload route " + upload.getNewFileName()); // RETURNS UNDEFINED
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't know why it comes back undefined. I'm passing the function. Am I missing something else?

I also included the uppy code is you need to see it.

uppy.js

```
// Import the plugins
const Uppy = require('@uppy/core');
const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload');
const Dashboard = require('@uppy/dashboard');


const uppy = Uppy({
    debug: true,
    autoProceed: false,
    restrictions: {
        maxFileSize: 1024000,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 3,
        minNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', 'video/*']
    }
})
    .use(Dashboard, {
        trigger: '.UppyModalOpenerBtn',
        inline: true,
        target: '#drag-drop-area',
        replaceTargetContent: true,
        showProgressDetails: true,
        proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
        animateOpenClose: true,
        note: 'Images and video only, 1–3 files, up to 1 MB',
        height: 470,
        browserBackButtonClose: true,
        theme: 'dark',
        metaFields: [
            {id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about'}
        ]
    });

uppy.on('file-added', (file) =>{
    console.log(file);
    uppy.setFileMeta(file.meta.id, {
       caption: file.name
    });
});

uppy.use(XHRUpload, {

    id: 'XHRUpload',
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    formData: true,
    fieldName: 'my_fieldName',
    metaFields: ['caption'],

});

uppy.on('upload-success', (file, response) => {

    console.log("File uploaded successfully ", file);

});

module.exports = uppy;
```

If you need to see other code let me know. Thank you!

By the way, I am using browserify to implement Uppy. :)

If Multer isn't the best way to upload a file to a server with Uppy, I will gladly take any better alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add this after restrictions in uppy.js:

n - is your new file name

```
restrictions: { 
   ... 
},
onBeforeFileAdded: (c, files) => {
    let n = Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2) + '.' + c.extension.toLowerCase()
    const m = {
        ...c,
        name:n
    }                    
    return m
}
```